# Imprimir ArrayList en TextView

Tags: android, android-studio, arraylist

hola estoy haciendo un juego y necesito al final del juego que me muestre los ultimos 10 puntajes, asique creo un arraylist donde voy almacenando los puntajes el problema es cuando quiero mostrar los puntajes en un textview no lo logro hacer se me detiene la aplicacion

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(9);

    public void resultado(){
    if (win) {
        result.setBackgroundResource(R.color.verde);
        result.setText("GANASTE!");
        result.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        puntaje=String.valueOf("Ganaste en la jugada "+puntajefinal);
        list.add(0,puntaje);
        mostrarrlista();
    } else {
        result.setBackgroundResource(R.color.rojo);
        result.setText("PERDISTE");
        result.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        puntaje=String.valueOf("Perdiste en la jugada "+puntajefinal);
        list.add(0,puntaje);
        mostrarrlista();
    }
}
public void mostrarrlista(){
    for (int i=0;i<=9;i++){
        txt0.setText(list.get(i));
    }
}
```

> 05-21 21:31:52.831 1168-1168/com.example.faku.ppt1 E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.faku.ppt1, PID: 1168
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.faku.ppt1/com.example.faku.ppt1.Puntaje}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null
>   object reference
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null
>   object reference
>           at com.example.faku.ppt1.Puntaje.mostrarrlista(Puntaje.java:66)
>           at com.example.faku.ppt1.Puntaje.resultado(Puntaje.java:53)
>           at com.example.faku.ppt1.Puntaje.onCreate(Puntaje.java:41)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)

Comment: Revisa la pestaña `LogCat` en la consola de la aplicación y comparte el error que te esta mostrando. Cuando te muestra error, el codigo es rojo, copialo y pegalo editando tu pregunta, para determinar por que se produce. Veo muchos posibles errores de null en este codigo. Sobretodo en el loop que itera la lista.

Comment: Que error te aparece? Por lo poco que yo se creo que con la funcion mostrarrlista() solo te apareceria el ultimo resultado porque se irian sobrescribiendo los datos. Creo que seria mejor utilizar un ListView, no?

Comment: ahi puse el error

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference at 


esta diciendo que cuando pongo settext referencio a un objeto nulo pero no es nulo no lo entiendo muy bien

Comment: @Houth si es `null`. Si esta llegando nulo, es porque el id no existe en el layout donde estas buscando la referencia o estas llamando el metodo antes de asignarle una referencia. Puedes compartir el codigo de como estas buscando la referencia y asignandola a `txt0`?. Puedes ver mi respuesta para un ejemplo de lo que debes hacer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es un `null` en la referencia del `TextView`:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null
>   object reference

Debes setear la referencia a la variable `txt0` antes de hacer `setText`.

Por ejemplo, si estas en un `Activity`, en el `onCreate` haces:

```
txt0 = findViewById(R.id.txt0);
```

Asumiendo que el id del `TextView` es `txt0` en el `Layout`. De todos modos, tu código solo mostrara el ultimo elemento en el `ArrayList`, por lo que no obtendrias el resultado que quieres. Ya que estas sobreescribiendo el texto al iterar la lista.

Si quieres un `TextView` que te imprima todos los resultados separados por un símbolo `("|")`, puedes hacer esto:

```
String resultados = "";
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
     if(i + 1 < list.size())
        resultados += list.get(i) + " | ";
     else
        resultados += list.get(i);

txt0.setText(resultados);
```

Si quieres crear tantos `TextViews` como cantidad de resultados en la lista, debes crear un [ListView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview?hl=es-419) o un [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) que tenga como hijo un `TextView`.

Comment: tenia la referencia como comentario u.u
ahi lo arregle y me salto otro error voy a probar la solucion que diste mas abajo hay una forma para que se pongan uno abajo del otro? vi por ahi que ponian "\n" puede ser_

Comment: probe como lo estaba haciendo pero haciendo la referencia y me tiro error y probe con tu metodo y me tira error tambien y se cierra todo

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
las 2 veces tiro este error

Comment: @Houth, seguro que copiaste el mismo código?, la condicion debe ser `<` en el for, no `<=`. Asegurate de que copiaste el código tal cual. Debe ser `i < list.size()` y si. Funciona el salto de linea por si lo quieres hacer asi. El simbolo fue solo un ejemplo.

Comment: tenias razon jaja gracias por tu ayuda, me sigue mostrando el ultimo resultado pero es por otro tema tengo que guardar el arraylist con sharedpreferences y creo que saldria funcionando Gracias!

Comment: @Houth Solo te muestra 1 resultado, porque a la lista solo agregas 1 resultado. Si quieres mas resultados debes agregarlo con `add` en la referencia `list`.

Comment: @Andrespengineer Recuerda que también se puede votar por la pregunta, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

debes de utilizar un arrayadapter para poder mostrar el contenido de el arraylist en el list view

podria hacerlo asi:

```
        ListAdapter adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<>(nombredetuclase.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,nombredetuarraylist);
        ListaMateriales=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListaMateriales);
        ListaMateriales.setAdapter(adaptador);
```

Comment: pero yo no quiero agregarlo a listview yo quiero agregar los contenidos en un textview

Comment: intenta cambiar el .size a .lenght ya que el size

Answer (score 0):

Una posible solución al null seria comprobar el tamaño de list y mandar el valor a la función que imprime el resultado.

```
public void resultado(){
if (win) {
    result.setBackgroundResource(R.color.verde);
    result.setText("GANASTE!");
    result.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    puntaje=String.valueOf("Ganaste en la jugada "+puntajefinal);
    list.add(0,puntaje);
    mostrarrlista();
} else {
    result.setBackgroundResource(R.color.rojo);
    result.setText("PERDISTE");
    result.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    puntaje=String.valueOf("Perdiste en la jugada "+puntajefinal);
    list.add(0,puntaje);
    int a = list.size();
    mostrarrlista(a);
 }
}
    public void mostrarrlista(int a){
for (int i=0;i<=a;i++){

    txt0.setText(list.get(i));
    }
}
```